# How to implement save or find on duplicate with spring jpa repository

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my business code, I am trying to implement logic that would insert an entity; and in the case of duplicate(DataIntegrityViolationException), would try to find the existing entity in database.

To find duplicates, I have unique constraint on columns with predefined message, and I check if the exception contains that message.

I am using spring boot with spring boot data jpa starter.

My logic looks like this:

```
val entity = try{
 repository.save(Entity(....))
}catch(ex: DataIntegrityViolationException){
  if(!indicatesDuplication(ex)) throw ex
  repository.findByUniqueKey(...)
}
```

I am using spring's declarative transaction support with default settings.

But the code doesn't work. It throws:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

After reading spring's documentation, I came to the conclusion that the problem lies in the default REQUIRED which creates logical transaction for every @Transactional method that all map to a single physical transaction. So even though I am catching the exception that is thrown by save method, because save is annotated with @Transactional without `noRollbackFor=[DataIntegirtyViolationException::class]`, it marks its logical transaction for rollback, and therefore I get as a result UnexpectedRollbackException.
Correct me if I am wrong here.

Then I thought that I might be able to fix this by overriding the save method inside my Repository interface and annotating it with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = [DataIntegrityViolationException::class])` .
But this still causes the same exception. I see that the transaction code uses a cache for SimpleJpaRepository methods and returns transaction settings that do no include my specified rollback rule(noRollbackFor = [DataIntegrityViolationException::class]).

Is there any solution to implement this type of code: save or else get within single transaction?

**UPDATE**

After debugging a little bit and reading more docs, I found that spring documentation suggests declaring(not overriding) methods in repository if I want to change the transaction settings.
I did this, but still getting the rollback.
After debugging,I see that the exception that is used for the no rollback rule is not spring's DataAccessException but jakarta's PersistenceException(`jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException`).
Shouldn't spring use exception translation and translate jakarta exceptions to spring DataAccessException hierarchy for spring repositories?

Answer (score 0):

A better, safer, solution is to lock, try to find an existing record, and if not found insert a new one.

That would, at least potentially, also be cheaper ESPECIALLY if you expect a lot of duplicates.

It would also prevent the rollback once and for all, as that is caused precisely by the attempt at a duplicate insert.

Comment: If I try to lock a row with FOR UPDATE (assuming the row doesn't exist) and only then try to insert, isn't there still a potential for duplicate exception since two requests might attempt to lock non-existing row and then try to insert the same record?